# the grouping column for an aggregate function is as a join condition?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I was reading some Oracle SQL resources and I found this SQL code:

```
 SELECT e.ename AS "NAME",
        e.sal AS "Salary", 
        e.deptno,
        AVG(a.sal) dept_avg
 FROM emp e, emp a
 WHERE e.deptno = a.deptno
 AND e.sal > ( SELECT AVG(sal) 
               FROM emp 
               WHERE deptno = e.deptno )
 GROUP BY e.ename, e.sal, e.deptno;
```

This SQL code is supposed to return every employee that gets more than the average salary of his department and display his name, his salary his department's ID and then the average salary in his department.

In order to return the dept_avg, we have to `group by` `deptno`, but the grouping columns are weird. What I guess, is that the grouping column is the column that is used as a join condition, the `a.deptno`. Is that true ? if not can someone please clarify it?

Comment: This is why using old style joins is dumb.

Comment: I don't think rewriting this query with `INNER JOIN` would make it any better.

Comment: @Timekiller why not?

Comment: @Hogan old-style seems just as clear to me as new style, the latter sometimes being too verbose and harder to follow.  That is, as long as no left/right joins (those horrible `(+)`) are involved. It's a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: @Timekiller - get real -- how often do you do any significant work and not have to use left joins.

Comment: @Hogan pretty much every other day, for example when I don't need left joins, but do need to inner join multiple tables together with dozens of conditions. Let's end this, to each their own.

Comment: I write queries more like Hogan and am fine with writing it like the way you noticed, OP. Consistency is the key. Either way you write, just examine queries' execution path to confirm that an out-of-the-ordinary path is not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `GROUP BY` and use `SELECT *`, you'll see what's happening.

`emp` is joined on itself, every employee with salary higher than average is joined with every other employee in his department, making an awful lot of rows. Then, from that data, average salary (from every other worker in dept) is counted again, using `GROUP BY`. It's impressively inefficient, look at other answers to see how it should have been done.

Comment: If that sounded weird, please cut me some slack - I'm not a native speaker :3

Comment: Your answer seems close to what I want to understand ! it's like we will get this result : 1st line after join  : name1, sal1, deptno1, sal1 ; second line after join : name1, sal1, deptno1, sal2, and so on .. then we group by name and salary and deptno to get the average of (sal1; sal 2; .... ) thanks :D

Comment: @Hogan oh, OK, thanks :3 @MichaelHeidelberg removing `GROUP BY` and examining what you're aggregating always helps a lot when debugging a weird / faulty legacy query, I use it often. Glad to help!

Comment: @Timekiller I think you did a pretty good job with that answer.

Comment: Yeah he did, @Timekiller : believe it or not, I can't test because I'm on Linux so I couldn't try because I don't have an SQL server installed on that system ://

Answer (score 2):

Maybe re-writing with more modern conventions makes it clearer?

```
WITH avgbydept as
(
   SELECT deptno, avg(sal) as avgsal
   FROM emp
   GROUP BY deptno
)
SELECT e.ename AS "NAME",
        e.sal AS "Salary", 
        e.deptno,
        AVG(a.sal) dept_avg
FROM emp e
JOIN emp a ON e.deptno = a.deptno
JOIN avgbydept abd ON e.deptno = abd.deptno
WHERE e.sal > abd.avgsal
GROUP BY e.ename, e.sal, e.deptno;
```

One thing this makes clear is that it has a "bug" of an extra join and group by -- To do as you say:

> This SQL code is supposed to return every employee that gets more than
>   the average salary of his department and display his name, his salary
>   his department's ID and then the average salary in his department.

I believe you want this

```
WITH avgbydept as
(
   SELECT deptno, avg(sal) as avgsal
   FROM emp
   GROUP BY deptno
)
SELECT e.ename AS "NAME",
        e.sal AS "Salary", 
        e.deptno,
        abd.avgsal as dept_avg
FROM emp e
JOIN avgbydept abd ON e.deptno = abd.deptno
WHERE e.sal > abd.avgsal
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` can throw us for a loop. Here's an easy way to think about grouping:

```
select field1, field1, sum(field3)
from ..
group by <all fields that do not participate in aggregate>
```

The query you noticed could be re-written somewhat like this:

```
select e.*, t.avgsal
from emp e
inner join (select deptno, avg(sal) avgsal from emp group by deptno) t 
  on e.deptno = t.deptno
where e.sal > t.avgsal
```

Now you can see that the subquery aliased with `t` will get average salary by department. We then use departments to join employee and our derived avg salary by department and eliminate the need for grouping.